# R.xml.preferences cannot be found?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to set up some simple preferences for an Android app, but can't get past this error: "xml cannot be resolved or is not a field."  I have cleaned, refreshed, restarted eclipse, and danced the jig - but I can't shake the error.  What am I doing wrong?

The preferences.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Dev options">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="devtools"
            android:title="Enable clearing user"
            android:summary="Enable clearing user" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

The java class file:

```
package com.myapp.prototype;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class GCPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load preferences from XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);    // error on this line ??
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where's your preferences file located? It should be: `<project>/res/xml/preferences.xml`.

Comment: and import com.myapp.prototype.R;

Comment: Had that has well. Namespace is a good thing, but it's a shame there are two "R" classes in the Android framework... Could have been avoided.

Answer (score 17):

I think you have missed an import (as said Vincent in comments). you should add:

```
import com.myapp.prototype.R;
```

The error also appears if you put in your code:

```
import android.R;
```

which is confusing because R is resolved but has no attribute that you defined in your XML file (of course, it is not the good R !).

Comment: Yeah, I resolved this after Vincent's answer via comments.  I just had preferences.xml in the wrong directory (under res/layout instead of res/xml).  Thanks for the follow up.

Comment: Encountered same issue, fixing the import statement and putting the settings file in place did the trick as per http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#DefiningPrefs.

Answer (score 4):

You must have a folder inside your `res/` directory called `res/xml` and inside it have your `.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors: 
I had the same problem. And One of the video I went through from lynda.com said that , the folder XML will be created with a file name.xml if we don't have one. But it dint' happen the way it was explained. I had to manually create a folder called "XML" under the "RES" folder and drag that xml file under it and error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem because I copied/pasted the xml from another project. Create the xml in the project with File=>new=>Android xml and then copy paste the xml code from the other project to the xml you just created.

Comment: did that work for you? how did you think it solved the issue? do you think it is about the privileges?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but my answer can be helpful for future viewers. I had the same problem, and it was because I had imported a wrong R class:

```
import android.R
```

You have to import your own project's generated R class:

```
import your.full.package.name.R
```

And of course you need to have res/xml/preferences.xml file in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for those who still have this error even after importing your own resource files, in my case, I just synced my project with the Gradle Files and it automagicaly resolved the issue.

In Android Studio hit

> File -> Sync Project with Grade Files

Hope it helped!