# How do I fix the R.xml.preferences error?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created couple of preferences in my preferences.xml folder but when I try to set it up in my Settings.java class I get a red underline under the xml in addPreferencesFromRecource(R.xml.preferences). I found this topic [R.xml.preferences cannot be found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098997/r-xml-preferences-cannot-be-found) where someone had the exact same problem as I do and was advised to include an import (in my case it is import com.example.anneholmes.R) and to check the location of the preferences.xml.
My preferences.xml are located in res/xml folder and I did the import; however, it did not fix the error in my case. How can I fix this error?

This is Settings.java code

```
package com.example.anneholmes;

import android.app.Activity;
import com.example.anneholmes.R; //did import
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class Settings extends Activity {
//code
        .
        .
        .

}
public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); // error 
        Preference submitPref = (Preference)findPreference("submitPref");
        submitPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new    OnPreferenceClickListener(){

                   //code
                      .
                      .
                      .
```

This is XML from preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<PreferenceCategory android:title="PERSONAL INFORMATION">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="firstName"
        android:title="First Name"
        android:summary="Enter your First Name"
        android:dialogTitle="Enter your first name">

    </EditTextPreference>

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="lastName"
        android:title="Last Name"
        android:summary="Enter your Last Name"
        android:dialogTitle="Enter your last name">

    </EditTextPreference>

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="email"
        android:title="Email address"
        android:summary="Enter your email address"
        android:dialogTitle="Enter your email address">

    </EditTextPreference>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Colors">
        <ListPreference 
            android:entries="@array/colors"
            android:entryValues="@array/colorSelected"
            android:key="textcolor"
            android:summary="Choose the Font Color"
            android:title="Foreground Color"/>
        <ListPreference 
            android:entries="@array/colors"
            android:entryValues="@array/colorSelected"
            android:key="color"
            android:title="Background Color"
            android:summary="Choose the Background Color"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

        <Preference 
            android:title="Save this Information"
            android:key="submitPref"/>


   </PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: is the file path **exactly** `/res/xml/preferences.xml`?

Comment: yes it is exactly that

Comment: Have you clean the project and tried again?

Comment: Yes I did clean the project and that gave me a mistake for R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never close your `<PreferenceScreen>` tag, so the XML here is invalid.

Since it is invalid, it won't compile, and thus won't have an int put into R that you are trying to reference from the Java code.

That is why it says it does not exist. It isn't explained very well anywhere, so I've had to find this on my own before.

Comment: Does your project have any errors anywhere else? In the XML files if there are errors, R.java will not compile and it will break a ton of stuff until you fix it.

Comment: I actually do have three errors in  my MainActivity.java

Comment: not sure what to tell you then. If you're using Eclipse try restarting it and/or saving the XML. I know in eclipse XML does not get recompiled until saving. And Eclipse/XML don't work together as well as I wish they did, sometimes requiring a restart to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".preferences"></activity>
```