# My project can not find R.xml

Tags: android, xml, analytics

My project can not find R.xml.
What is problem[image]

Comment: From my experience it is usually means there is an error within an xml file.

Comment: @Justin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098997/r-xml-preferences-cannot-be-found . Check this

Comment: Check your LogCat to see if  there is any error in xml files. Also try to clean the project.

Comment: Clean your project then restart eclipse then rebuild your project and hopefully it will work